# adding objects in a container inside other object is null with arc

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsmutableset

I am using Apple's ARC. I have tow classes: one that has a NSMutableSet and one that I want to put inside that NSMutableSet.

So when I do the following:

```
    ContainerClass* contClass = [[ContainerClass alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        SmallClass* myClass = [[SmallClass alloc] init];
        [myClass setinfo:i];

        [contClass.mySet addObject:myclass];
    }

    for(SmallClass* cls in contClass.mySet){
         NSLog(@"%@", cls);
    }
```

the result is: (null) (null) (null) (null) etc.

Does it means that SmallClass is being released by ARC? How can I solve it (I can't do retain of course)? Calling copy on myclass instance results with error because I didn't implement copy for myClass (in the pre-ARC way I would just do retain on it).

**ContainerClass** code:

```
@interface ContainerClass : NSObject {
    NSString* _icon;
    NSMutableSet* _mySet;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* icon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet* mySet;

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
@implementation ContainerClass

-(id) init
{
    _myset = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    return [super init];
}

@synthesize mySet = _mySet;

@end
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for your ContainerClass?

Comment: `@interface ContainerClass : NSObject {
    NSString* _icon;
    NSMutableSet* _mySet;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* icon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet* mySet;

@end`




and the .m file:


`@implementation PoiSet

-(id) init
{
    _myset = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    return [super init];
}

@synthesize mySet = _mySet;

@end`

Comment: sorry i am new to this comments system. here is a better look:
 http://codetidy.com/1725/

Comment: You can just edit your post and add your new code. For example under your **note** section, you could add an **edit** section and put the code there.

Comment: thanks i edited it, also thanks for the corrections, i will try to improve next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your ContainerClass init method is wrong. Try the following:

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
      _myset = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Hope it helps.